# jQuery: улучшение кода функции для замены одних тэгов на другие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не вдаваясь в то, зачем это нужно: эта функция заменяет собтвенные тэги (как, впрочем, и любые существующие, имя которых указано в параметре) на `span` с нужным классом:

```
function convertToHTML(tag){
    $(tag).replaceWith(function(){
        return '<span class="'+tag+'">'+$(this).text()+'<span>';
    });
  }
```

Я сделал данную функцию на основе этой ([источник](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)):

```
 $(".l2 .item").replaceWith(function(){
     return ' <li class="item" > '+$(this).text()+', я кому сказал! </li>';
 });
```

Можно ли убрать из моей функции вложенную, улучшив таким образом код?
(Если желаете дать ответ в `jsfiddle`, вот рабочий [код](https://jsfiddle.net/cokvaLx3/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(tag).replaceWith('<span class="'+tag+'">'+$(tag).text()+'<span>');
```

*Update*

Прошу прощения, замена не эквивалентна.

Если набор `$(tag)` включает больше одного элемента, то `$(tag).text()` - это склеенный `innerText` их всех. В то время как `replaceWith` с функцией вызывает эту функцию отдельно для каждого заменяемого элемента в контексте (`this`) этого элемента.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Comment: Не за что. Успехов в программировании.